# How to generate unique strings based on regular expression in node js

Tags: node.js, regex, unique

I want to generate unique strings based on  a regular expression and that string is to be stored as a key in the database .How can I do that in node js.

pattern: "^([0-9]{5,6}-)?[^-]+$" .

I tried "randexp" but it's not giving unique strings everytime .
Randexp for the above pattern gave something like this--->> 38085-a:[' \8YOIHeVMr_3v~

Also i want to have  simpler strings which can be used as a ID in my code.
How can I go about it...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
npm [crypto-random-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-random-string), it gives better solution as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i have to follow a regular expression....("^([0-9]{5,6}-)?[^-]+$" )and want to have unique strings based on this expression...is there any other way..?